# Printing in both double and single quotes

Tags: python, quotes, double-quotes, single-quotes

I am on [exercise 8](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex8.html) of Learning Python the Hard Way, and I don't understand why certain lines in a `print` function are printed in single or double quotes.

The program reads as follows:

```
formatter = "%r %r %r %r"

print formatter % (
"I had this thing.",
"That you could type up right.",
"But it didn't sing.",
"So I said goodnight."
)
```

The output is as follows:

```
'I had this thing.' 'That you could type up right.' "But it didn't sing." 'So I said goodnight.'
```

Why is the third sentence in double quotes and why are the others in single quotes?

Answer (score 2):

The `formatter` is using `%r` so that each `str` is printed in quotes.  The function that does that defaults to using single quotes as the delimiter, but if it sees a single quote in the string, and no double quotes in the string, it switches to using double quotes as the delimiter.

For example, try:

```
print "%r" % '''This string has a ' and a " in it.'''
```

Answer (score 2):

you are using `%r` which calls the `__repr__` method. what you seem to want is rather `%s` which calls the `__str__` method.

in the string in question you already have a `'`; thats why `repr()` gives it out quoted in `"`.

Comment: The OP's question was why the quotes are different, not why the quotes were there.